# Menelaus' theorem in 3D space

Tags: geometry

Consider a tetrahedron ABCD. Let A′, D′, B′ be the points on the sides AD, DB and BC such that AA′ = A′D, DD′ : D′B = 2 and BB′ : B′C = 3. Let F be the intersection point of the line AC with the plane passing through the points A′, D′, B′. Find AF : FC.

What I tried:

By Menelaus' theorem $\frac{AA'}{A'D}\frac{DD'}{D'B}\frac{BB'}{B'C}\frac{CF}{FA}=1$, so $\frac{1}{1}\frac{2}{1}\frac{3}{1}\frac{CF}{FA}=1$, then CF/FA=1/6

I am not sure about my solution, as I am not expected this question would be that easy.

Menelaus' theorem: Let $ABCD$ be a non-planar 4-gon in space. Let the marked points $X,Y,Z,W$ lie on lines $AB, BC, CD$ and $DA$ respectively. Then the 4 marked points $X, Y, Z, W$ belong to one plane if and only if the following 3-D Menelaus's condition holds:$
\frac{AX}{XB} \cdot \frac{BY}{YC} \cdot \frac{CZ}{ZD} \cdot \frac{DW}{WA} = 1$